# Mac OSX : is there a way to know with code if the user's Macbook is charging?

Tags: xcode, macos, operating-system, system

Is there a way to know with code if the user's Macbook is charging ?

Thanks !

Comment: Something similar has been asked before, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272552/battery-status-in-osx
Please let us know if following the directions given in the answers there also work for your question.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751132/mac-get-battery-charging-status-plugged-in-or-not